# Uploading hundreds of profiles through the MYSQL database on this WP template?

Tags: javascript, mysql, wordpress

I apologize in advance if my question doesn't make sense, but to put it simply. I would like to basically automate and upload a few hundred profiles and jobs to this WP template: https://www.enginethemes.com/themes/freelanceengine/#developer

It is not possible to do this through the Admin Panel according to the developer of this template, and it would need to be done manually by creating individual accounts.

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to have a automated java script (or something similar to selenium) read off of a excel doc (and image folders) and upload all the profiles through the MYSQL Database.

Can this be done by coding it in? Does it need to be done within the MYSQL database?

Do please let me know if this doesn't make sense and I'll do my best to re-explain. Much thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "Profiles"?  Is this to be a WP user? Or something different? (NOTE that the template / theme has nothing to do with this).

Comment: Are you talking about something like this? https://wordpress.org/plugins/import-users-from-csv-with-meta/

Comment: This is a freelance marketplace theme,  so there would be freelancers as well as employer accounts on the site. I would like to essentially mass upload a few hundred fabricated freelance profiles through the backend,  without setting up each account manually.

Comment: Yes! A plugin like that could work! Does this plugin allow for images to also be uploaded per profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are three solutions. They allow uploading docs/csv files and images to the wordpress database. After reading through the documentation, it looks like you would have to add a url for each image instead of uploading the actual image straight to the database.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-ultimate-csv-importer/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-csv-to-database/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/import-users-from-csv-with-meta/

Comment: Hi Chase, thank you for this information. I will give this a try and see if this works!